# Find players who have played only cricket?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I have a table game having records like:

```
name  games
---------------
jack  cricket
jack  football
ryan  basketball
ryan  basketball
adi   cricket
```

I want the name of player who have only played cricket.

desired output:

```
adi cricket
```

my query:

```
SELECT count(name)
    ,games
FROM game
WHERE games = 'cricket'
GROUP BY games
HAVING count(name) = 1
```

Is there any other way?

Comment: I think your table should contain at least one primary or unique key, specially in int data type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       gms1.name,
       gms1.games
FROM   game gms1
WHERE  gms1.games = 'cricket'
  AND  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   game gms2
                   WHERE  gms1.name = gms2.name
                     AND  gms1.games <> gms2.games);
```

In words: select all players that did cricket and did not do anything else.

Answer (score 1):

You can do aggregation :

```
select name, min(games)
from game 
group by name
having min(games) = max(games) and min(games) = 'cricket';
```

You can also use `not exists` :

```
select g.*
from games g
where not exists (select 1 from games g1 where g1.name = g.name and g1.games <> 'cricket');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following query.

```
SELECT *
FROM Testing
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT name
        ,Count(games) AS Cnt
    FROM Testing
    GROUP BY name
    ) TEMP ON Testing.name = TEMP.name
    AND Cnt = 1
    AND Testing.games = 'cricket'
```

You can find the [live demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3a4c9d98c0dd21fc1ffaada449e9d21f).

Answer (score 0):

You can use count distinct for this to create a quite simple query. Full example included.

```
declare @games table
(
    name varchar(10)
    , games varchar(10)
)
insert @games values
('jack', 'cricket')
, ('jack', 'football')
, ('ryan', 'basketball')
, ('ryan', 'basketball')
, ('adi', 'cricket')


select name
    , count(*)
from @games
GROUP BY name
HAVING count(distinct games) = 1
    and MAX(games) = 'cricket'
```